# Anyone have any idea with this. I have this datepicker working on FF but seem not working on IE

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I found this datepicker events but not working on IE. I don't know what is wrong with this code.

```
var Event = function(text, className) {
        this.text = text;
        this.className = className;
    };


var events = {};
events[new Date("18/Jan/2013")] = new Event("Drinks @ Seymours - Alumni Event", "Yes");
events[new Date("16/Jan/2013")] = new Event("Retired Staff Luncheon", "Yes");
events[new Date("13/Jan2013")] = new Event("October Spring Lunch - Alumni Event", "Yes");


$("#dates").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/M/yy',  
    firstDay: 1,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    onSelect: function(date) {
        $('#CAT_Custom_241423').val(date);
        $('#submit-btn-webapp').trigger('click');
    },
    beforeShowDay: addClass 
});

function addClass(date) { 
    var event=events[date];
    if(event){
        return[true,event.className,event.text];
    }
    else {
        return[true,'',''];
    }
}
```

It is working fine on ff, Google Chrome. 
Here's the the working code on jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7U56z/

Comment: Have you checked the console in IE (press `F12`) for any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are the event keys (the generated dates). If you try the following in IE:

```
 alert(new Date("18/Jan/2013"));
```

You'll get an error (invalid date). So you'll never get a match in your function. Define the keys like this (or simular to this):

```
 events[(new Date(2013, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0))] = new Event(....)
 // format in this case is:
 // new Date(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)
 // month starts with 0.
```

and it works. You don't have to set hour, minute and second in this case. You just have to be sure that the generated key is a valid date and matches the date coming from the datepicker.

By the way, I would rename your "Event" Object to something different, because there is already an window.event that is a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, all i do is just copy paste some code, make some revision on it.
regarding on this. Is there a way to change months to be Short Month name? Can I use using the dateformat?

Comment: @user2014797 you mean in the date constructor? As far as I know, no.

Comment: yes. events[(new Date(2013, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0))]
to be events[(new Date(2013, Jan, 18, 0, 0, 0))]

Comment: @user2014797 what should work is the full month name, but not a short one.

Comment: events[(new Date(2013, Jan, 18, 0, 0, 0))] I've try changing the numeric month to full name January but doesn't seem to work. I also added dateformat? but can't find to work. Any suggestion how to make it work using the full month?

Comment: @user2014797 ok, I tested a few more variants: This would be valid: new Date("January 18, 2013 00:00:00"); and it seems this one too: new Date("Jan 18, 2013 00:00:00"), or this: new Date("Jan 18 2013");